# Create number prefix in VBA

Tags: string, vba, numbers

I have several revision numbers I need to create folders from. So, lets say `{4, 12, 534}`. From this, I need to create folders that can be sorted accordingly;

```
\004\..
\012\..
\534\..
```

So, what I need to is to get the highest number and then see, how many filling zeros I need for every foldername so they are sorted correct after creating them.

How can I do this using VBA (Excel)? I tried converting them to strings and then dealing around with String operations, but this didn't quite work out.

I hope someone has a nice idea for this...

Comment: Have you tried to use CInt(value) prior to the comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest to precompute the max then loop again and pad;

```
Dim nums() As String: nums = Split("4,12,534,9999", ",")
Dim i As Long
Dim max As Long

For i = 0 To UBound(nums)
    If (Len(nums(i)) > max) Then max = Len(nums(i))
Next

For i = 0 To UBound(nums)
    nums(i) = String(max - Len(nums(i)), "0") & nums(i)
    Debug.Print nums(i)
Next
```

Comment: `Len()` is supposed to give me the Lenght of the variable, right? But when I do `Dim Test As Integer: Test = 1` `Len(Test)`, it gives me `2`? How come?

Comment: Because a vba integer is 16 bit, which is 2 bytes, to get its length as a string you would len(cstr(i))

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way is with `Format` (or `Format$`):

```
dim s As String

    s = Format$(revNum, "000")
```

Using `"000"` as the "format string" tells the function to pad with leading zeros, whereas `"###"` tells it not to pad. The difference between the function versions is the return type: `Format` returns a Variant (String), while `Format$` returns an actual String.

Comment: That's really neat. But it doesn't cover how to determine the maximum number and then using different length paddings. Still, nice to see such a feature.

Comment: It does assume that you know in advance the maximum number of places that you want to pad out to--any number of `"0"` placeholders work just as well, with the resulting string being padded to that length. Values larger than the format string are **not** truncated, though they're obviously not padded.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why a simple string operation won't work out.

```
Select Case Len(folderstring)
  Case 1
    folderstring = "00" & folderstring
  Case 2
    folderstring = "0" & folderstring
  Case Else
    ' Do nothing here
End Case
```

OR

```
Dim zeroarray(1 To 3) As Variant

zeroarray = Array("00","0","")
folderstring = zeroarray(Len(folderstring)) & folderstring
```

Comment: @ApoY2k, well this way is definitely more efficient, but it really doesn't matter for such a trivial task.  I'm glad you were able to find the solution you wanted.